# Advanced screen-scraping using curl

Tags: python, curl, screen-scraping

I need to create a script that will log into an authenticated page and download a pdf.

However, the pdf that I need to download is not at a URL, but it is generated upon clicking on a specific `input` button on the page. When I check the HTML source, it only gives me the url of the button graphic and some obscure `name` of the button `input`, and `action="."`.

In addition, both the url where the button is and the form name is obscured, for example:

- url = `/WebObjects/MyStore.woa/wo/5.2.0.5.7.3`
- input name = `0.0.5.7.1.1.11.19.1.13.13.1.1`

How would I log into the page, 'click' that button, and download the pdf file within a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mechanize or twill. HttpFox or firebug can help you to build your queries. Remember you can also pickle cookies from browser and use it later with py libs. If the code is generated by javascript it could be possible to 'reverse engineer' it. If nof you can run some javascript interpret or use selenium or windmill to script a real browser.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) module can help.

I think that url on clicking the button maybe generated using javascript.So, to run javascript code from python script take a look at [Spidermonkey](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey).

Answer (score 1):

You could observe what requests are made when you click the button (using Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome). You may then be able to request the PDF directly.

It's difficult to help without seeing the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

As Acorn said, you should try monitoring the actual requests and see if you can spot a pattern.

If not, then your best bet is actually to automate a fully-featured browser, that will be able to run Javascript, so you'll exactly mimic what a regular user would do. Have a look at [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming) on the Python Wiki for ideas, check the section *Python Wrappers around Web "Libraries" and Browser Technology*.